# Custom Segues In Swift

Tags: swift, segue

I am coding an app in Swift 4, using Xcode 11, and I have a welcome screen for users to use. There is a button on the welcome screen, and I want it to take the user from the welcome screen to the main screen of the app. I don't need a fancy animated transition or anything, I just want a custom segue that prevents them from ever getting back to the home screen, as opposed to the normal segues, which let you get back to the original page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably also want to record that the user has seen the welcome screen and never show it again, right? You should include that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a segue like that, you can't go back because there is no navigation bar between these ViewControllers.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this that are all about managing the presentation of your application.

First, if you're using a UINavigationController after pushing a view on to the sack you can manually set the `viewControllers` of the navigation controllers to only be the current view controller, this eliminates the "back" behavior.  It's a solid technique to have in your back pocket. For example you could do:

```
func onButtonPress(_ sender: Any) {
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = [self.navigationController.topViewController]
}
```

That's the most trivial case, but it shows setting the `viewControllers` property to an array made up of *just* the top most view controller of the navigation stack.  There's also a really nice `setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController], 
               animated: Bool)` if you want to animate a presentation to a new view controller that's worth looking at depending on the effect you're interested in.

Second, you can in your app delegate present a modal view controller over your root view controller.  When the user hits the button `dismiss` the modal.  Boom! They can never go back.

Third, you can swap out the `rootViewController` of the window.  This is the trickiest option, and probably shouldn't be done, but it is an option.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Sorry to ask a follow-up, I'm still a bit new to Swift. Could you explain how I might set the viewControllers on the nav controller to be only the current one? Would I be doing that change in code? If so, where do I code for a nav controller? In the root viewController?
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Happy to help.  I expanded my answer a bit on using the NavigationViewController.  The "where" in your code base is a bit more specific to your project, my first guess is going to be in whatever VC your button is defined, but that could changed depending on the architecture of your app, so don't take that as gospel.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use a Show Modal (Present) segue. This moves to a new view controller and, if *you* do not provide a way to move back to the welcome screen, the user can't go back to it — the app, from now on, takes place as if the new view controller were its root.

You will also want to take steps to make sure that on future launches the welcome screen is not shown again if it has already been shown. The standard approach is to put code into your `didFinishLaunching` that sets the window's initial `rootViewController` based on whether the welcome screen has been shown previously. Basically what you're doing is just skipping past the welcome screen on all but the first launch of the app.